# Windows azure publish fails

Tags: asp.net, windows, azure, certificate

I followed the instructions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff683676.aspx) to set up crendentails for Windows Azure deployment 
but I keep getting this error :

> authentication failed verify that your credentials are valid or download them again
>   The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'.
>   The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

What might be the cause

Answer (score 1):

This error means that the specified in Visual Studio certificate/SubscriptionID are not matching in Windows Azure portal.

Ensure that you've uploaded a correct public key (.cer) to your Windows Azure *Management Certificates* area (not SSL certificates area).
Also, make sure that you have the private key in your certificate store.